# how can I create a virtualenv variable inside a makefile

Tags: bash, python, make, virtualenv

I am trying to create a makefile to compile a full project.

I want to start by creating a virtualenv variable inside it using `mkvirtualenv` wrapper like:

```
train: create_env
    echo "create env?"

create_env:
    ( \
    mkvirtualenv -p python3.6 RC_RSC_env; \
    )
```

but I am getting this error:

```
( \
mkvirtualenv -p python3.6 RC_RSC_env; \
)
/bin/sh: 2: mkvirtualenv: not found
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'create_env' failed
make: *** [create_env] Error 127
```

Comment: Does it work if you use the full path to the `mkvirtualenv` command? See `type -a mkvirtualenv`.

Comment: @terdon, sorry I can't find the full path. The output doesn't contain any directory!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what this `mkvirtualenv` thing is. Also show us the output of `type -a mkvirtualenv`. The normal command for creating python venvs is `virtualenv` as far as I know.

Comment: @terdon please keep in mind that `type -a` causes a syntax error with most shells,so never use `-a` in such a context.In special since it is unknown what has been installed as `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Thanks, @schily, I thought it was more portable than that.